# How to avoid duplicate ViewChildren in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have over 10 components where the following code is duplicated:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
    @ViewChildren(CheckboxComponent) checkboxes: QueryList<CheckboxComponent>;

     public onSelectedAll(value: boolean): void {
        this.checkboxes
            .toArray()
            .slice(1)
            .forEach((element) => {
                element.checked = value;
            });
    }

    public onSelectedOne(value): void {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

How want to pull out this code outside, what it should be service or just custom exported class, function?

How to do that properly in Angular and easy inject in component if needed?

Comment: make a single component with the repeated code to import 10 times, no?

Comment: Each component has own logic, not only this. Do you mean create common component and extend it?

Comment: better if you can share with us the logic that you can't share

Comment: your code doesn't have logic at all, it's simple use a single multiple-checkbox-component with appropriate input and output

Comment: you need a stronger abstraction. IE, a `CheckboxFieldComponent` that wraps your checkboxes and can control them all if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't have enough details on what are the semantics of these components and if a better implementation can be done (for example instead of querying for your ViewChildren, you could have a model of your checkbox list). I am only going to answer from a high-level point of view.

In this case, you can leverage OOP and use inheritance, you can extract your common logic to a class (you can make it abstract if necessary).

**Common Class**

```
export abstract class CommonComponent {
   /* Put common Methods and Fields here
      including @ViewChildren and any other annotated fields */
}
```

**Component Implementation**

```
export class MyComponent extends CommonComponent implements OnInit {
   /* Put here Methods and Fields specific to this Component
      In this component, you can make use of all the fields and methods
      that are public or protected from the parent class
      (public ones can be used in template as well */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to provide details of your (checkboxes component)

```
@ViewChildren(CheckboxComponent) checkboxes: QueryList<CheckboxComponent>;
```

You should also consider your setup, however if you want to stay with this setup than, don't use @ViewChildren to get data from your child component instead use EventEmitters to receive data in your parent component.

Whenever the state of your checkbox changes emit event to parent with data.

Check angular docs for EventEmitters:

https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to : "*Have a custom directive with this functionality and use it with your checkbox*"

Comment: Could you share an sample?

Comment: In my case I need two directive, one to select current checkbox, another to select all checkboxes on the page, right?

Comment: Could I get access from directive to ` @ViewChildren` component?

Comment: ElemRef for referencing your element can be utilized as an alternative for '@ViewChildren' in the directive.

Comment: will share a sample shortly